# how to sql join/merge

Tags: mysql, sql, join, merge

I have two tables and I would like to update a field from table 2 to table 1.  Ideas?

```
/*Table 1:*/


id | name| adress| type
--+------+--------+----
1 | jill | 1 main | 444
2 | bill | 2 main | 888



/*Table 2:*/


type_id | type
--------+-------
444     | green 
888     | blue 



/******GOAL*****/

id | name| adress| type
--+------+--------+----
1 | jill | 1 main | green
2 | bill | 2 main | blue
```

I want to replace the contents of table 1/column 'type' with contents of table2/column 'type.'

Thanks folks!!

Comment: Can you explain what you have tried to get the result you are looking to achieve? This seems like basic SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are updating integer value with strings

in case you have the field has varchar then this should work

```
UPDATE TABLE1 T1
JOIN TABLE2 T2
on T1.type = T2.type_id
set T1.type = T2.type
```